# Can't figure out how to instantiate generic class returned from function with condition like <S, T extends S>

Tags: java, android, android-studio, generics

Can't figure out how to get this work:

```
//Have a tiny CustomServiceLoader implementation
public class MyServiceLoader {

    static private Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> CONTENTS = new HashMap<>();

    static public <S, T extends S> void registerClassForInterface(Class<T> c, Class<S> i) {
        if (c == null) {
            CONTENTS.remove(i);
        } else {
            CONTENTS.put(c, i);
        }
    }

    static public <S, T extends S> Class<T> getClassForInterface(Class<S> i) {
        return (Class<T>)CONTENTS.get(i);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
// classes registration works perfect event check for interface conformance (e.g. T extends S really works here!):
    MyServiceLoader.registerClassForInterface(Model.class, APIAsyncLoaderTask.class);

// but I can't figure out how to instantiate a class returned from my service loader:
Class c = GiftdServiceLoader.getClassForInterface(APIAsyncLoaderTask.class);
mLoaderTask = c.newInstance(); // 'new c();' also couldn't work
```

And compiler error:
[image: incompatible types compiler error]

also I have a strange tip for that method which is

```
public final Class<T> extends Object implements Serializable, AnnotatedElement, GenericDeclaration, Type
```

But I cannot see my interface there. I'm getting same when using both: **abstract class + class** and **interface + class**

**How do I make it work properly? I'm wondering is it at least possible?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the raw type `Class`.

```
Class c = GiftdServiceLoader.getClassForInterface(APIAsyncLoaderTask.class);
```

All generatic types and generic type parameters in any method invoked on such a reference are erased.

Parameterize it correctly

```
Class<APIAsyncLoaderTask> c = MyServiceLoader.getClassForInterface(APIAsyncLoaderTask.class);
```

Note that you should use only the interface type if you aren't sure of what you'll be receiving from the call to `getClassForInterface`.

For example, I can do

```
MyServiceLoader.registerClassForInterface(NotModel.class, APIAsyncLoaderTask.class);
// but I can't figure out how to instantiate a class returned from my service loader:
Class<Model> c = MyServiceLoader.getClassForInterface(APIAsyncLoaderTask.class);
Model mLoaderTask = c.newInstance(); // 'new c();' also couldn't work
```

and it will fail with a `ClassCastException`.

Generics are not powerful enough to prevent this.

---

I believe you meant to have

```
CONTENTS.put(i, c);
```

in your `registerClassForInterface` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have the raw form of the `Class` class in the preceding line:

```
Class c = GiftdServiceLoader.getClassForInterface(APIAsyncLoaderTask.class);
```

Therefore, the `newInstance()` method returns an `Object`, which can't be assigned to an `APIAsyncLoaderTask`.

But coming out of a `Map<Class<?>, Class<?>>`, the best you can do with generics is `Class<?> c = ...`, and `newInstance` still returns an `Object`.  You don't have the information at compile time to determine if the `Class` `c` represents an `APIAsyncLoaderTask`.

However, you can enforce an upper bound on the value of the `HashMap`.

```
static private Map<Class<?>, Class<? extends APIAsyncLoaderTask>> CONTENTS = new HashMap<>();
```

Your `registerClassForInterface` method will need that upper bound also.

```
static public <S extends APIAsyncLoaderTask, T extends S> void registerClassForInterface(
    Class<T> c, Class<S> i) {
```

Then you can `get` a `Class<? extends APIAsyncLoaderTask>` out of the `HashMap`, and `newInstance()` will return the erasure of the upper bound -- an `APIAsyncLoaderTask`.

Comment: Are you limiting the registry to `APIAsyncLoaderTask` subtypes?